# Outlook, set reminder to follow up when sending email

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm using the outlook webmail application, but I'd switch to any version that I can implement this.
What I would like is when sending an email, that it give me the option to get a reminder to follow up in a certain amount of time. As an example, say I have a list of people I need to contact. I'd like to be able to try contacting them through email first, but on sending it set a reminder in outlook that after so many days for me to; check for a response , or follow up with phone call, or cross them off my contact list.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found same option on the web mail(outlook.com), but this can be realized on Outlook desktop client. You may refer to following rule description:

[image]